# SQL:How to count record which distinct?

Tags: sql

The data source:

```
id  idx num
1   1   1
2   1   2
3   2   3
4   2   3
5   3   4
6   3   4
7   3   5
```

I need count record which the same idx and count num's type.

I hope result:

```
idx num
1   2
2   1
3   2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is a `DISTINCT` count:

```
SELECT idx, COUNT(DISTINCT num) AS num
FROM mytable
GROUP BY idx
```

Comment: Oh, this is what I want.Thanks.